# merging virtual attributes for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model Declaration and a modelDeclarationlines. It's a has many relation with accepts_nested_attributes_for :declarationlines. This works great, but the declarationline form has 2 virtual attributes 'amount_whole' and 'amoutn_decimal', which get merged into the attribute 'amount' when submitting the form. This works on create where I have this:

```
# Cycle declaration lines to merge amount_whole and amount_decimal into amount
@declaration.dec_declarationlines.each do |line|
  line.amount = (line.amount_whole.to_s + '.' + line.amount_decimal.to_s).to_d
end
```

But on update I have this, which prevents me to merge the virtual attributes because I have no access to the declarationlines:

```
@declaration.update_attributes(params[:dec_declaration])
```

Any ideas how to merge the virtual attributes when updating the declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have access to the declarationlines:

1) `params[:dec_declaration][:declarationlines_attributes]`

2) u can try `@declaration.assign_attributes(params[:dec_declaration])` and then `@declaration.dec_declarationlines.each ...`

Comment: Thanks! This was missing: @declaration.assign_attributes(params[:dec_declaration]). I didn't know how to get the attributes.